# Microsoft Visual Basic Excel error 1004 en el tiempo de ejecución

Tags: excel, vba, vb, microsoft, ejecutar

tengo este código tan sencillo (estoy empezando con vb de excel) y lo ejecuto y funciona okey hasta un punto que salta el error 1004 en tiempo de ejecución: Error definido por la aplicación o el objeto.
Lo he rescrito numerosas veces y con todas las posibilidades de seleccionar rangos, celdas... pero no consigo dar con el problema.
A ver si alguien podría ayudarme.
Es un programa que hace la media de los valores que escojas de la columna 4:

```
Sub medias()

    Dim fila_ini As Integer
    Dim fila_fin As Integer
    Dim fila As Integer
    Dim suma As Integer
    Dim media As Integer
    Dim nfilas As Integer
    Dim rng As Range

    fila_ini = InputBox("Número de la primera fila", "Fila inicio")
    fila_fin = InputBox("Número de la última fila", "Fila final")

    fila = fila_ini
    suma = 0
    
    For fila = fila_ini To fila_fin
        rng = ActiveSheet.Range(fila, 4)
        suma = suma + rng.Value
         
    Next fila
    
    nfilas = fila_fin - fila_ini + 1
    media = suma / nfilas
    ActiveSheet.Range(1, 5).Value = media

End Sub
```

Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
' Usa Cells
' Cells trata la hoja como una matriz pudiendo hacer referencia a una celda
' indicando la fila y la columna Rango.Cells(fila,columna)
' En este caso en el código se ha omitido el rango y se asume por defecto Application
' Es decir, todas las celdas de la hoja activa

Sub medias()

    Dim fila_ini As Integer
    Dim fila_fin As Integer
    Dim fila As Integer
    Dim suma As Double
    Dim media As Double
    Dim nfilas As Integer

    fila_ini = InputBox("Número de la primera fila", "Fila inicio")
    fila_fin = InputBox("Número de la última fila", "Fila final")

    suma = 0
    
    For fila = fila_ini To fila_fin
        suma = suma + Cells(fila, 4)
    Next fila
    
    nfilas = fila_fin - fila_ini + 1
    media = suma / nfilas
    Cells(1, 5).Value = media

End Sub
```

Comment: Explicale porque debe usar cells

Comment: Y por qué este código resuelve la pregunta? Procura siempre incluir una breve explicación del porqué y de cómo se debe usar :)

Comment: Lo de Cells es cierto, pero en su código tenía otros errores, como por ejemplo, el `rng =...` sin un `Set`

Comment: Hola Juan Carlos, muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Ha sido muy útil y me funciona correctamente. Gracias a todos por las explicaciones!

Answer (score 2):

Tu código está casi bien. Te da error el objeto `Range`

> [Objeto Range
> (Excel)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/excel.range(object))

Tienes escrita esta línea:

`ActiveSheet.Range(fila, 4)`

Es incorrecto, porque la forma correcta de usar el objeto range es con un **Texto** (un *string*), que represente la coordenada de la celda. VBA espera leer algo como `A1` o `B17`. Pero no espera leer algo en plan `(1,2)`

La notación que tú utilizas es cuando se usa el objeto `Cells` que, a efectos prácticos, es lo mismo que range, con las mismas propiedades y métodos.

> [Propiedad Range.Cells
> (Excel)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/excel.range.cells)

Luego también tienes puesto:

`rng = ActiveSheet.Range(fila, 4)`

Sin embargo, tu variable `rng` es de tipo objeto (es decir, que dentro vas a almacenar un objeto, no un dato numérico o alfanumérico). **Todas las variables objetos se tienen que instanciar con SET**, siempre.

Es decir, en tu caso tendrías que hacer:

`Set rng = ActiveSheet.Cells(fila, 4)`

Esto lo que hace es que dentro de `rng` está almacenada la celda que esté en la columna D y en la fila `fila`. Ycuando digo celda, me refiero a **todas** sus propiedades y **todos** sus métodos, no únicamente al valor.

Así que tomando tu código literalmente como lo has hecho, te funcionaría si lo pones así:

```
Sub medias()

    Dim fila_ini As Integer
    Dim fila_fin As Integer
    Dim fila As Integer
    Dim suma As Integer
    Dim media As Integer
    Dim nfilas As Integer
    Dim rng As Range

    fila_ini = InputBox("Número de la primera fila", "Fila inicio")
    fila_fin = InputBox("Número de la última fila", "Fila final")

    fila = fila_ini
    suma = 0
    
    For fila = fila_ini To fila_fin
        Set rng = ActiveSheet.Cells(fila, 4)
        suma = suma + rng.Value
         
    Next fila
    
    nfilas = fila_fin - fila_ini + 1
    media = suma / nfilas
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 5).Value = media

End Sub
```

Ahora bien yo te sugiero el siguiente código por varias razones:

1. Mas optimizado, porque hace lo mismo con menos líneas
2. Tú declaras `suma` y `media` como `Integer`, que solo admite números **enteros**. Si la media es decimal, se redondeará a un número entero. Ten mucho cuidado con estas cosas porque no es un error de programación que VBA detecte, pero es un fallo gordo del programador si fuera necesario trabajar con decimales.

Un ejemplo, si yo tengo los 10 primeros números, del 1 al 10, la media en realidad es 5.5, pero tu código devuelve 6 únicamente porque estás trabajando en `Integer`.

Te recomiendo que leas los tipos de datos **básicos**, es imprescindible dominar esto para aprender a programar.

> [VBA tipos de datos
> básicos](https://excelyvba.com/tipos-de-variables-en-vba/)

Respecto a tu código, lo simplificaría así:

```
Sub medias()
'Todas las variables de tipo numérico se inicializan con valor 0, no hace falta especificar algo como suma=0
'Todas las variables de tipo texto se inicializan como cadenas vacías, es decir, ""
'Todas las variables Booleanas se inicializan como Falso
'En tu código no hay booelanas ni de texto, pero así lo sabes

Dim Fila_Ini As Long 'Long para poder seleccionar filas por encima de 32000, que es el límite de Integer
Dim Fila_Fin As Long
Dim Suma As Double 'Double para poder trabajar con decimales
Dim Fila As Long

Fila_Ini = InputBox("Número de la primera fila", "Fila inicio")
Fila_Fin = InputBox("Número de la última fila", "Fila final")

For Fila = Fila_Ini To Fila_Fin Step 1
    Suma = Suma + ActiveSheet.Cells(Fila, 4)
Next Fila

ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 5) = Suma / (Fila_Fin - Fila_Ini + 1)

End Sub
```

Y ya si quisiera un código realmente resumido y aprovechando casi todo el potencial que tiene Excel, usando en tiempo de ejecución la función `Average (Promedio)`posiblemente lo reduciría todavía más a:

```
Sub medias()
Dim Fila_Ini As Long 'Long para poder seleccionar filas por encima de 32000, que es el límite de Integer
Dim Fila_Fin As Long


Fila_Ini = InputBox("Número de la primera fila", "Fila inicio")
Fila_Fin = InputBox("Número de la última fila", "Fila final")

With ActiveSheet
    .Cells(1, 5).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(.Range(.Cells(Fila_Ini, 4), .Cells(Fila_Fin, 4)))
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Elier! Gracias por la optimización del código. Mucho mejor que el mío inicial :) Gracias también por las explicaciones que me han sido muy útiles. Gracias!